# Trying to change Appengine JAVA SDK in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, google-app-engine-patch

I've upgraded the Eclipse pluging to 3.7 and the JAVA SDK to 1.6.6. I've noticed some problems, so I'm trying to go back to 1.6.5 but the Eclipse plugin always copy 1.6.6 jars to WEB-INF.
What I have to do to force the Plugin to change to 1.6.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to manually remove the new JAR then copy the old JAR in your `WEB_INF/lib` ?
Does the plugin automatically adds the new JAR in the lib during the compiling ?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the top level folder and select properties which should be the last thing. Look at Java Build Path and click on the Libraries tab. You can configure the SDK that the project uses from there.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. It succeed in the build path, but in WEB-INF 1.6.6 jars are copied instead of 1.6.4 or 1.6.5

Answer (score 0):

Got to "Help" - "About Eclipse" - Select "Installation Details" - Select "Installation History" tab

It will show the recently installed history.

There you have options to "Delete" or "Revert" back the installations done.